# Problems with android alarm manager, when the app is closed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

During development of a small android app, I am having problem in running an alarm manager, after the app is terminated by the user. While the app is running in the foreground or background, everything works fine.

I did the following steps:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver" ></receiver>
```

**MainActivity.java**

Within the OnClick method of a button, I call

```
startAlert( x*60*1000);
```

x is a class-wide visible variable

```
public void startAlert(long timeInMillis){ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+(timeInMillis),pendingIntent);
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm in " + x + " Minuten",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**MyBroacastReciever.java**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context,MainActivity.link); 
                                         player.start();
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

What should I do to get the `alarmManager` successfully running, after the app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the alarm manager in the service. The foreground service is used to keep our application alive even though the main application has been quit by the user. And then the alarm manager could trigger the code in the broadcast receiver class